# How to translate my own sentence using Attention mechanism?

Tags: python, nlp, language-translation, seq2seq

For every language translation repos, I can see the existing sentences which are translated. If i give my own sentence ( evnthough the words of my own sentence are existed in the dataset) the translation I am getting is the existing sentence from the dataset.

Please help me to resolve this issue

Reference link for the code
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/seq2seq_translation_tutorial.html

Reference sentence which I tried to translate on [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuoSE.png)

Comment: Give examples, with links to the repos

Comment: @leleogere I edited the question with the ref link and ref sentence. Please help me

Comment: Unfortunately I wont be able to help as I don't have any knowledge in language processing. But this information will likely help when someone else will come across this post

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Probably it shows the model is overfitted, did you feed data correctly during training? did your data contain enough diverse examples? It can be a good idea to share what you have done so far!

Comment: Yes I did As per the tutorial. It is translating the sentences from the dataset. But, If I change the last word from the sentence, it is translating that into existing sentence from the dataset. @meti